# failed to open stream: Invalid argument with exclamation marks in URL

Tags: php, google-maps

https://www.google.co.uk/s?tbm=map&fp=1&gs_ri=maps&suggest=p&authuser=0&hl=en&pb=!2i14!4m12!1m3!1d36371.595804441626!2d-2.4949300500000002!3d53.74963355!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1600!2i740!4f13.1!7i10!10b1!12m6!2m3!5m1!2b0!20e3!10b1!16b1!19m10!1e1!1e13!1e2!1e5!1e3!1e10!1e12!1e15!1e27!4smaps_sv.tactile!20m49!1e1!1e13!1e2!1e5!1e11!1e4!1e3!1e10!1e12!1e15!1e27!2m2!1i203!2i100!3m1!2i4!5smaps_sv.tactile!6m3!1m2!1i86!2i86!7m26!1m3!1e1!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e2!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e2!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e4!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b1!3e2!2b1!4b1!9b0!22m3!1sJf4OVtPaHMj-UL_-hugD!3b1!7e81!23m1!4b1!26m9!1e12!1e15!1e13!1e3!1e27!2m2!1i80!2i80!4smaps_sv.tactile!37m1!1e81&q=downing%20street&pf=p&tch=1&ech=14&psi=Jf4OVtPaHMj-UL_-hugD.1443823133674.1

When trying to read the .txt file that shows on the URL above with `fopen` it returns failed to open stream: Invalid argument.

I have tried `urlencode` but it gives the same error

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.google.co.uk/s?tbm=map&fp=1&gs_ri=maps&suggest=p&authuser=0&hl=en&pb=!2i14!4m12!1m3!1d36371.595804441626!2d-2.4949300500000002!3d53.74963355!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1600!2i740!4f13.1!7i10!10b1!12m6!2m3!5m1!2b0!20e3!10b1!16b1!19m10!1e1!1e13!1e2!1e5!1e3!1e10!1e12!1e15!1e27!4smaps_sv.tactile!20m49!1e1!1e13!1e2!1e5!1e11!1e4!1e3!1e10!1e12!1e15!1e27!2m2!1i203!2i100!3m1!2i4!5smaps_sv.tactile!6m3!1m2!1i86!2i86!7m26!1m3!1e1!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e2!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e2!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e4!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b1!3e2!2b1!4b1!9b0!22m3!1sJf4OVtPaHMj-UL_-hugD!3b1!7e81!23m1!4b1!26m9!1e12!1e15!1e13!1e3!1e27!2m2!1i80!2i80!4smaps_sv.tactile!37m1!1e81&q=downing%20street&pf=p&tch=1&ech=14&psi=Jf4OVtPaHMj-UL_-hugD.1443823133674.1";
$myfile = fopen(urlencode($url), "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo $myfile;
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you try to open `urlencode($url)` then you access to

> https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2Fs%3Ftbm%3Dmap%26fp%3D1%26gs_ri%3Dmaps%26suggest%3Dp%26authuser%3D0%26hl%3Den%26pb%3D%212i14%214m12%211m3%211d36371.595804441626%212d-2.4949300500000002%213d53.74963355%212m3%211f0%212f0%213f0%213m2%211i1600%212i740%214f13.1%217i10%2110b1%2112m6%212m3%215m1%212b0%2120e3%2110b1%2116b1%2119m10%211e1%211e13%211e2%211e5%211e3%211e10%211e12%211e15%211e27%214smaps_sv.tactile%2120m49%211e1%211e13%211e2%211e5%211e11%211e4%211e3%211e10%211e12%211e15%211e27%212m2%211i203%212i100%213m1%212i4%215smaps_sv.tactile%216m3%211m2%211i86%212i86%217m26%211m3%211e1%212b0%213e3%211m3%211e2%212b1%213e2%211m3%211e2%212b0%213e3%211m3%211e3%212b0%213e3%211m3%211e4%212b0%213e3%211m3%211e3%212b1%213e2%212b1%214b1%219b0%2122m3%211sJf4OVtPaHMj-UL_-hugD%213b1%217e81%2123m1%214b1%2126m9%211e12%211e15%211e13%211e3%211e27%212m2%211i80%212i80%214smaps_sv.tactile%2137m1%211e81%26q%3Ddowning%2520street%26pf%3Dp%26tch%3D1%26ech%3D14%26psi%3DJf4OVtPaHMj-UL_-hugD.1443823133674.1

that's invalid.

Second, your `$myfile` is a [resource](http://php.net/manual/it/language.types.resource.php). So you need to work with that, example:

```
$url = "https://www.google.co.uk/s?tbm=map&fp=1&gs_ri=maps&suggest=p&authuser=0&hl=en&pb=!2i14!4m12!1m3!1d36371.595804441626!2d-2.4949300500000002!3d53.74963355!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1600!2i740!4f13.1!7i10!10b1!12m6!2m3!5m1!2b0!20e3!10b1!16b1!19m10!1e1!1e13!1e2!1e5!1e3!1e10!1e12!1e15!1e27!4smaps_sv.tactile!20m49!1e1!1e13!1e2!1e5!1e11!1e4!1e3!1e10!1e12!1e15!1e27!2m2!1i203!2i100!3m1!2i4!5smaps_sv.tactile!6m3!1m2!1i86!2i86!7m26!1m3!1e1!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e2!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e2!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e4!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b1!3e2!2b1!4b1!9b0!22m3!1sJf4OVtPaHMj-UL_-hugD!3b1!7e81!23m1!4b1!26m9!1e12!1e15!1e13!1e3!1e27!2m2!1i80!2i80!4smaps_sv.tactile!37m1!1e81&q=downing%20street&pf=p&tch=1&ech=14&psi=Jf4OVtPaHMj-UL_-hugD.1443823133674.1";
$myfile = fopen(($url), "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo stream_get_contents($myfile);
fclose($myfile);
```

or just

```
echo file_get_contents($url);
```